# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#, исключения

Сумма по столбцу в dataGridView.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с такой вот проблемой. Заполняю dataGridView3 таким вот способом:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Загружаем таблицу из теплосетей
    OleDbConnection _connection = new OleDbConnection();
    StringBuilder ConnectionString = new StringBuilder("");
    ConnectionString.Append(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;");
    ConnectionString.Append(@"Extended Properties=Paradox 5.x;");
    ConnectionString.Append(@"Data Source=C:\Teplo\TepSeti\;");
    _connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString.ToString();
    try
    {
        _connection.Open();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error openning database! ");

    }
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Tepotp", _connection);
    adapter.Fill(dataset5);
    _connection.Close();
    // Загружаем таблицу из ОИК "Тепло"
    if (dataset5.Tables.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка, результат не содежит строк");
        return;
    }
    dataGridView3.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    bindingSource5.DataSource = dataset5.Tables[0];
    dataGridView3.DataSource = bindingSource5;
}
```

Теперь хочу подсчитать сумму по столбцу и занести в label таким способом:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row  in dataGridView3.Rows)
{
    int partialsum = 0 ;

    bool tryParse = int.TryParse(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() ,out partialsum );
    if (tryParse)
    {
      sum += partialsum; //row.Cells[2] - это колонка с числовыми значениями

    }
}              
label6.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Но выходит ошибка:

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Не могу понять почему.

Comment: Может напишите в какой строке ошибка?

Comment: Дело на форме происходит

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, ошибка где-то тут:

```
row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()
```

Попробуйте заменить на

```
(row.Cells[2].Value ?? "").ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело на форме или в ASP.NET происходит?

если второе, посмотри есть ли у твоей DataGrid биндинг после назначения source.

Comment: Пошаговую отладку сделай и мучайся.
чтобы знать в какой строке ошибка.